# Get a value from a string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I'm receiving a string like this one:

```
"????log L 05/27/2012 - 08:02:57: \"Acid<1><STEAM_ID_PENDING><CT>\" say \"password somepass\"\n\0"
```

How can I get `somepass` from this string?

Comment: As commented to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700300/regex-get-username-from-string-c-sharp) What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string test = "????log L 05/27/2012 - 08:02:57: \"Acid<1><STEAM_ID_PENDING><CT>\" say \"password somepass\"\n\0";
string[] array = test.Split('\"'); ;
Console.WriteLine(array[3].Split(' ').Last());  //somepass
```

Or:

```
string password = string.Empty;

for (int i = 0; i < test.Length - 8; i++)
     if (test.Substring(i, 8) == "password")
          for (int j = i + 8; test[j] != '\"'; j++)
               if (test[j] != ' ')
                   password += test[j];

Console.WriteLine(password); //somepass
```

I was interested by the answer given by `buckley`, so I did a benchmark using these three methods to get `"somepass"`, using this code:

```
string test = "????log L 05/27/2012 - 08:02:57: \"Acid<1><STEAM_ID_PENDING><CT>\" say \"password somepass\"\n\0";

Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
timer.Start();

for (int n = 0; n < 10000000; n++)
{
     string[] array = test.Split('\"');
     string password = array[3].Split(' ').Last(); //somepass
}

timer.Stop();
TimeSpan time = timer.Elapsed;
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", time.Minutes, time.Seconds, time.Milliseconds / 10));

timer.Reset();
timer.Start();

for (int n = 0; n < 10000000; n++)
{
    string password = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < test.Length - 8; i++)
         if (test.Substring(i, 8) == "password")
             for (int j = i + 8; test[j] != '\"'; j++)
                 if (test[j] != ' ')
                      password += test[j]; 
} //somepass

timer.Stop();
time = timer.Elapsed;
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", time.Minutes, time.Seconds, time.Milliseconds / 10));

timer.Reset();
timer.Start();

for (int n = 0; n < 10000000; n++)
{
    string resultString = null;
    Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"""password (.*?)\\""\\n\\0""");
    resultString = regexObj.Match(test).Groups[1].Value; //somepass
}

timer.Stop();
time = timer.Elapsed;
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", time.Minutes, time.Seconds, time.Milliseconds / 10));
```

The result is *(snapshot)*:

[image]

I can conclude that use the `Split()` method (is **1475%**) faster than use `Regex` method in this case.

Answer (score 3):

The match you want is in group 1 of

```
\"password (.*?)\\"\\n\\0"
```

In C# this becomes

```
string resultString = null;

Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"""password (.*?)\\""\\n\\0""");

resultString = regexObj.Match(subjectString).Groups[1].Value;
```